# how to relate one ponyorm entity attribute with several other entities?

Tags: python, ponyorm

I'm starting working with an existing database where attribute `foo` of table `A` is related to more then one other table, `B.foo` and `C.foo`. How do I form this relationship in ponyorm?

The database is organized like below.

```py
from pony import orm
db = orm.Database()

class POI(db.Entity):
    '''Point of interest on a map'''
    name = orm.PrimaryKey(str)
    coordinateID = orm.Optional(('cartesian', 'polar')) # doesn't work ofc

class cartesian(db.Entity):
    coordinateID = orm.Required(POI)
    x = orm.Required(float)
    y = orm.Required(float)

class polar(db.Entity):
    coordinateID = orm.Required(POI)
    r = orm.Required(float)
    phi = orm.Required(float)
```

Of course `x`,`y` from `cartesian` and `r`,p`hi` from `polar` could be moved to `POI`, and in the database I work with, that's the same situation. But the tables are divided up between stakeholders (`cartesian` and `polar` in this example) and I don't get to change the schema anyway. I can't split `coordinateID` in the schema (but it would actually be nice to have different attributes of the python class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to relate one attribute for several enties in PonyORM except for the case when these entities are inherited from the same base entity, then you can specify base entity as the attribute type and use any of inherited entity as a real type.

If you use existing schema that you can't change, you probably can't use inheritance and need to specify raw id attribute instead of relationship:

```py
from pony import orm
db = orm.Database()

class POI(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "table_name"
    name = orm.PrimaryKey(str)
    coordinate_id = orm.Optional(int, column="coordinateID")

class Cartesian(db2.Entity):
    _table_ = "cartesian"
    id = orm.PrimaryKey(int, column="coordinateID")
    x = orm.Required(float)
    y = orm.Required(float)

class Polar(db2.Entity):
    _table_ = "polar"
    id = orm.PrimaryKey(int, column="coordinateID")
    r = orm.Required(float)
    phi = orm.Required(float)
```

And then you can perform queries like this:

```py
left_join(poi for poi in POI
              for c in Cartesian
              for p in Polar
              if poi.coordinate_id == c.id
                 and poi.coordinate_id = p.id
                 and <some additional conditions>)
```

Note that all entities used in the same query should be from the same database. If entities belongs to two different databases, you cannot use them in the same query. And need to issue separate queries:

```py
with db_session:
    poi = POI.get(id=some_id)
    coord = Cartesian.get(id=poi.coordinate_id)
    if coord is None:
        coord = Polar.get(id=poi.coordinate_id)
    <do something with poi and coord>
```

But in case, for example, of SQLite you can attach one database to another to make them appear as a single database.

Comment: This approach solves my problem, but it's seems to me like sort of a workaround wrt the original question: wouldn't the answer be: you can't? Btw: the `db2` was a typo, sorry for that - I edited them out of the question.

Comment: Yes, you can relate atttribute with two unrelated entities. I updated the answer